# Can't connect VPN with OpenVPN on Network Manager Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn, openvpn

I would like to connect to my new VPN (HMA) with openVPN and Network Manager on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I can establish a connection with a VPN server but I can't use Web browsers ("Address not found"). Also I can ping IP addresses but I can't ping domain names.

Comment: @CravateRouge - You have the freedom to post your question and the answer as well. However, posting and accepting an answer to your own question has certain limits where you can refer "[**Can I answer my own question**](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). And not to worry, as we're always here to help/support our users at any time with love & care. :)

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to explain the exact problem you get when you try to browse from a browser :)

Comment: Browsers I know aren't explicit, they just say "Address not found" or something like that ^^ but you're right I'll add some symptoms that I experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is DNS settings so you can try this

- [CHANGING YOUR DNS SETTINGS ON
  WINDOWS, MAC, ANDROID, IOS, LINUX](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202720776-Changing-your-DNS-settings-on-Windows-Mac-Android-iOS-Linux)

If it didn't work you can modify /etc/resolv.conf and add `nameserver "DNSaddress"`

But resolv.conf is a dynamic file so to add this line permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

and add your DNS servers like this `nameserver "DNSadress"`.

I hope this post could help others.

- List item